# Moongose returns nested values

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have a problem with the moongose. I get the array with the structure
`[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` ->  each object looks like this `{order: {…}}`
I do not want this `{order: {…}}` I just want to have have properties without nesting like this

`[{_id: "123", price: 2000}]`.

Mongoose schema

```
const order = new Schema<IOrder>(
  {
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { collection: "orders", timestamps: true },
);
```

part of users schema

```
orders: [
    {
      _id: false,
      order: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Order", required: true },
    },
  ],
```

saving logic

```
  const order = new Order({ totalPrice });
  await order.save();
  const currentUser = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId });
  currentUser!.orders = [...currentUser!.orders, { order: order._id }];
  await order.save();
  await currentUser!.save();
  res.status(200).json({ totalPrice: totalPrice });
```

Comment: You could map over the array to get the desired result

Comment: Is the goal here to change the structure of what is _stored_ in the database or just modify the structure of what is returned to the client when queried?  Sounds like you're directly asking about the latter, but if that's how you always want to retrieve the document  then I think you may want to consider the former.